# Is my proof of Proca Lagrangian local gauge invariance correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-invariance

My task was to prove that the first term of the Proca Lagrangian is invariant under local gauge transformations. I’m new to Ricci calculus and think I’ve misinterpreted what I was supposed to do, and probably the process in general. Was my justification for step (1) correct?

[image: my proof]

Comment: In the second line you forgot to put the gauge transformation $A\rightarrow A+d\lambda(x)$ in the leftmost term, which would cancel with the second term as the function $\lambda$ is analytic in $x$, so the derivatives commute. Your justification regarding linearity is not true as the only thing you need to assume about $\lambda$ is exactly that it's analytic (otherwise the derivatives don't necessarily commute), but otherwise completely arbitrary.

Comment: Wow! I don't know how I didn't see that in all my reattempts. My linearity justification was straw clutching, since I was used to these problems canceling and thought this one didn't. Thank you very much.